irregular sequence milliseconds transform
I have a time irregular sequence of minutes with milliseconds
msc <- c("58:49.5", "59:05.3","59:37.0", "59:50", "00:00.4", "01:41.5","03:49.5")

the transition from "59:50"  to  "00:00.4" means that a new hour has begun.
the vector with time may not necessarily be exactly this one and there is not always a transition to a new hour, I just showed the worst option.
The question is
How can I create a vector that will count the number of minutes and milliseconds passed from the first date to the last.
first data 58:49.5 = 00:00.0
last data 03:49.5
result vector
"00:00.0"  "00:00.1"   "00:00.2"  ........... "05:00:00"


How many elements should the result vector have?

First, add hours to the data
library(lubridate)

hmsc <- hours(cumsum(c(0, diff(as.numeric(ms(msc)))) < 0)) + ms(msc)

then apply seq for each set of times, convert to period and then to a date time.
Finally paste the minutes and the milliseconds. This has to be done in 2 steps because otherwise the milliseconds will have rounding errors.
dat <- unique(unlist(
  apply(cbind(seq_along(hmsc)[-length(hmsc)],
              seq_along(hmsc)[-1]), 1, \(x){
    Date <- as_datetime(seconds_to_period(
      seq(as.numeric(hmsc[x[1]]), as.numeric(hmsc[x[2]]), 0.1)))
 })))

res <- dat - dat[1]

paste0(format.Date(res, "%M:%S"), 
       sub(".*(\\..*)", "\\1", sprintf("%0.1f", res)))

output
   [1] "00:00.0" "00:00.1" "00:00.2" "00:00.3" "00:00.4" "00:00.5" "00:00.6"
...
[2990] "04:58.9" "04:59.0" "04:59.1" "04:59.2" "04:59.3" "04:59.4" "04:59.5"
[2997] "04:59.6" "04:59.7" "04:59.8" "04:59.9" "05:00.0"


Hi, I wasn't clear enough in my question and you seem to have misunderstood what I meant. I have edited my question to make it more clear, please review it.

You can simply subtract the first element from the resulting vector. I will add an edit...

I think you haven't taken into account the problem with the transition to a new hour. Here is the result of your script. Here is the result of your script.
[697] "59:59.1" "59:59.2" "59:59.3" "59:59.4" "59:59.5" "59:59.6" "59:59.7" "59:59.8"  [705] "59:59.9" "00:00.0" "00:00.1" "00:00.2" "00:00.3" "00:00.4" "00:00.5" "00:00.6"

...and if you subtract the first element you get [1] "00:00.0" "00:00.1" "00:00.2" "00:00.2" "00:00.3" "00:00.5" "00:00.6". How many elements should the resulting vector have?

Please update your code with subtraction

The input data is a bit awkward but here's my attempt.
library(tidyverse)
msc <- c("58:49.5", "59:05.3","59:37.0", "59:50", "00:00.4", "01:41.5","03:49.5")

msc2 <- lubridate::ms(msc)

df <- tibble(msc, msc2)


df <- df %>%
  mutate(change = msc2 < lag(msc2)) %>%
  mutate(change = if_else(row_number() == 1, FALSE, change))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(n_changes = cumsum(change))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(msc3 = msc2 + hours(n_changes))

final <- df %>%
  mutate(dummy_time = origin + msc3 - first(msc3)) %>%
  mutate(total_sec = interval(first(dummy_time), dummy_time) / dseconds(1),
         minutes = (total_sec) %/% 60,
         seconds = (total_sec) - (minutes * 60)) %>%
  mutate(diff = paste(str_pad(minutes, 2, pad = "0", side = "left"), 
                           str_pad(round(seconds, 1), 2, pad = "0", side = "left"), 
                           sep = ":")) %>%
  select(msc, diff)
final
#> # A tibble: 7 × 2
#>   msc     diff   
#>   <chr>   <chr>  
#> 1 58:49.5 00:00  
#> 2 59:05.3 00:15.8
#> 3 59:37.0 00:47.5
#> 4 59:50   01:0.5 
#> 5 00:00.4 01:10.9
#> 6 01:41.5 02:52  
#> 7 03:49.5 05:00

Created on 2024-08-08 with reprex v2.0.2

Hi, You should have a series with a step of one millisecond as in my example.
"00:00.0"  "00:00.1"   "00:00.2"

I misunderstood as I thought you wanted a count of minutes and seconds using the irregular series.
